# Displaying another activity instead MainActivity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, settings, display

How I can display another activity instead of the main, if in the settings, in the list of RadioButtons marked a particular item?
For example:
If you select A - activity A displayed.
If you select B - activity B displayed.
If you select C - activity C displayed.

Comment: Check this out.. I hope it will help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776116/how-do-i-dynamically-choose-which-activity-to-launch-when-opening-an-app

Comment: When you say  "If you select A - activity A displayed. If you select B - activity B displayed" you mean the XML of those activities?

Comment: @We'reAllMadHere yes

Comment: Why don't you use a fragment and replace it on radio button click? That would be the proper way.

Comment: Then I guess you could use something like that `Intent i = new Intent(that, Activity_B.class);` `startActivity(intent);`. What that does is, when something you want occurs, it changes activities and goes from your current to activity B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, get which button is currently selected from the radio group. After you get the current radio button, simply check the button's text or a tag and launch the activity based on it.

Try something like this,

```
radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                // checkedId is the RadioButton selected
                // get selected radio button from radioGroup
                int selectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                // find the radio button by returned id
                radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);

                // toggle views on radio button click
                if (radioButton.getText().toString().equals("Activity A") {
                   startActivity(new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, ActivityA.class))
                } 
                else if (radioButton.getText().toString().equals("Activity B")) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, ActivityB.class))
                } 
                else if (radioButton.getText().toString().equals("Activity C")){
                    startActivity(new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, ActivityC.class))
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sharedPreferences. Just store A in sharedPreferences if 1st radio button is selected, B if 2nd and so on.
While creating an intent, you can check what is stored in CallingActivity SharedPreference, If its default value then call main, otherwise use switch case to call specific activity.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("CallingActivity", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor sEditor = sharedPref.edit();
sEditor.putString("ActivityName","A");
sEditor.commit();
```